# Refining a Isabelle type declaration

Tags: isabelle

In some theory, say TA, I define an opaque type, say OC, using Isabelle's typedecl construct:

```
    typedecl C
```

Let's suppose that I now want to define a refinement for the opaque type 'C' in some other theory that uses 'TA'. For example, to say that 'C' in that new theory is of type 'String'.

How can I do this? Is there a direct way to this in Isabelle? Or do I need to define coercion functions that map one type to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have declared a constant or type in Isabelle, you cannot change the specification afterwards. Since you have declared `C` as an unspecified type, all the definition packages of Isabelle will refuse to refine the specification. However, if you bypass them, you can do so, but you do so at your own risk.

Essentially, you want to say that type `C` is isomorphic to type `string`. Normally, you would do that with the command `typedef` in Isabelle, which declares a new type and establishes the isomorphism with the non-empty set. This is the very basic mechanism to introduce new types in HOL, i.e., every other package for type declarations (like `record` and `datatype`) build on `typedef`. The isomorphism is established by declaring two constants `Abs` and `Reps` between the old type and the new type and by asserting the axiom `type_definition Rep Abs A` where `A` is the non-empty subset of the old type. Thus, if you want to later refine `C` to type `string`, you can just declare new functions `Abs_C :: string => C` and `Rep_C :: C => string` and axiomatise `type_definition Rep_C Abs_C UNIV` using `axiomatization`. After that, you know that `C` is isomorphic to `string` and you can use `Abs_C` and `Rep_C` as coercions.

With this approach, you are responsible for not introducing inconsistencies. Say, if you take this approach in two theories and refine `C` to different types in each of them, then you'd better never merged these two theories (or anything derived from them), otherwise you can probably derive `False`. Isabelle does not and cannot check this for you! The conventional `typedef` avoids this problem by making combining the declaration and the specification into one atomic step. Yet, `typedef` is still somewhat axiomatic, as the Isabelle reference manual remarks, and it might be abused in some corner cases to introduce inconsistencies.

If you do not want to add axioms yourself, you have to change `C` from a fixed type to a type variable everywhere. Then, you can instantiate it later as needed and you do not need coercions either. However, in your general part, you have to generalise everything to type variables and (depending on your applications) this might not even be expressible in HOL.

A few years ago, the [AWE tool](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/~cxl/awe/) offered to instantiate unspecified types using theory morphisms. Unfortunately, the latest version works with Isabelle2009-1, so this is not really an option.